# Spring boot YAML config : Parametred keys

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

Is spring boot allow to use parametred keys using YAML ?

Example of parametred key:

```
myapp.configured.key: This is your email > {0} And this is your name > {1}
```

And in my Java class i want to do some thing like this:

```
@Inject
private Environment env;//import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;


String email = "email@email.com"
String name = "User Name";

String key=env.getProperty("myapp.configured.key", email, name);

System.out.println(key);
```

And the out put will be like this :

```
This is your email > email@email.com And this is your name > User Name
```

Comment: Why would you want that if you can do `String key=String.format(env.getProperty("myapp.configured.key"), email, name);` (assuming you can change your placeholders to `%s`)

Comment: Becuase in Spring  using MessageSource(org.springframework.context.MessageSource) we can do some things like above (kind of comparaison).But seems good alternatif ;).Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your `email` and `name` are also configuration keys, you can refer to them in your message (but it's a bit weird)

```
myapp.configured.email: email@example.com
myapp.configured.name: John Smith
myapp.configured.key: This is your email > ${myapp.configured.email} And this is your name > ${myapp.configured.name}
```

The `Environment` has no such API and as a Spring Boot user you shouldn't even touch that stuff (check `@ConfigurationProperties` for type safe binding of configuration).

Comment: Hi @Stéphane Nicoll, the email and name are not included in my file config :( . I should get them from my controller and set them after

Comment: Then you should store the formatted string and do the formatting yourself.