# How to set the values from command line for placeholders in spring-boot's Yaml file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I'm having a `application.yml` file that holds some placeholders e.g.

```
security:
  user:
    password: ${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
```

I've tried running e..g

```
./gradlew :project:bootRun -DADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
./gradlew :project:bootRun -PADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
./gradlew :project:bootRun --ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
```

but the placeholder is not replaced. What is the proper way for passing command-line value to placeholder templated variables in YAML file?

Comment: Somewhat duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/q/32970766/1240557

Answer (score 2):

The parameters are not automatically passed in via the bootRun task (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/592).

I add this to my `build.gradle` to get the behavior you are asking for:

```
bootRun {
    // allows ./gradlew bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
    systemProperties System.properties
}
```